# comparing two unequal values in coq

Tags: coq, compcert

I'm proving this lemma:

```
Require Import compcert.lib.Coqlib.
Require Import compcert.lib.Integers.
Require Import compcert.common.Values.

Lemma test: forall (val1 val2: int), ((Vint val1) <> (Vint val2)) -> (Some (Val.cmp Ceq (Vint val1) (Vint val2)) = Some Vfalse).
Proof.

Admitted.
```

I've tried unfolding `not, Val.cmp, ...` and using `rewrite` over `H` but didn't go anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original theorem that you had was false, unfortunately. The problem was that `Val.cmp` returns `Vundef` if one of the compared values is not an integer. Check the definition of `cmp` and `cmp_bool` [here](http://compcert.inria.fr/doc/html/Values.html).

The new theorem that you have is true, but is not stated in a very useful form. It is better to state it like this:

```
forall val1 val2, val1 <> val2 -> Val.cmp Ceq (Vint val1) (Vint val2) = Vfalse
```

Having the `Vint` and `Some` constructors around the equalities does not change the truth value of your theorem, but makes it harder to apply in most concrete settings. This result should follow by unfolding `Val.cmp`, `Val.cmp_bool`, and `Int.cmp`, and rewriting with `Int.eq_false`.

Comment: good point. I made an edit to the lemma. Can you look at it again?

Comment: `val1` and `val2` aren't of type `int`. They are of type `val`. So I can't use Int.eq_false.

Comment: No, `val1` and `val2` _are_ of type `int` in the statement that I wrote down. It is `Vint val1` and `Vint val2` that are of type `val`.

Comment: I meant in the one that I need to prove are of type `val`.

Comment: Your `test` lemma is also quantifying over `val1` and `val2` of type `int`... Maybe you wanted to prove something else?

Comment: `VAL1` and `VAL2` here `VAL1 <> VAL2` are of type `val`. The unequality is over type `val` not `int`.

Comment: I think you're referring to the fact that your statement says `Vint val1 <> Vint val2` instead of `val1 <> val2`, as I had on mine. If that's the case, all you have to do is use the `Vint val1 <> Vint val2` hypothesis to prove `val1 <> val2`, as needed by `Int.eq_false`. You can probably do it with `assert (val1 <> val2). { congruence. }`, after introducing `Vint val1 <> Vint val2`.